# How add plot to subplot matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have plots like this

```
fig = plt.figure()
desire_salary = (df[(df['inc'] <= int(salary_people))])
print desire_salary
# Create the pivot_table
result = desire_salary.pivot_table('city', 'cult', aggfunc='count')

# plot it in a separate step. this returns the matplotlib axes
ax = result.plot(kind='bar', alpha=0.75, rot=0, label="Presence / Absence of cultural centre")

ax.set_xlabel("Cultural centre")
ax.set_ylabel("Frequency")
ax.set_title('The relationship between the wage level and the presence of the cultural center')
plt.show()
```

I want to add this to `subplot`. I try

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3)
...
ax = result.add_subplot()
```

but it returns 
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'add_subplot'`. How can I check this error?

Comment: do you want to plot 6 plots?

Comment: @MaxU, Yes, I want to add 6 plot to one. I have that separately, but I want to unite that

Comment: check the link, i've provided in my answer - i was doing there almost the same (i was using seaborn.boxplot instead of barplot, that you want to use)

Comment: Try always to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking questions. In case of _pandas_ questions please provide sample _input_ and _output_ data sets (5-7 rows in CSV/dict/JSON/Python code format _as text_, so one could use it when coding an answer for you). This will help to avoid _situations_ like: `your code isn't working for me` or `it doesn't work with my data`, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`matplotlib.pyplot`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#module-matplotlib.pyplot) has the concept of the current figure and the current axes. All plotting commands apply to the current axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 3)     # 6 axes, returned as a 2-d array

#1 The first subplot
plt.sca(axarr[0, 0])                # set the current axes instance to the top left
# plot your data
result.plot(kind='bar', alpha=0.75, rot=0, label="Presence / Absence of cultural centre")

#2 The second subplot
plt.sca(axarr[0, 1])                # set the current axes instance 
# plot your data

#3 The third subplot
plt.sca(axarr[0, 2])                # set the current axes instance 
# plot your data
```

---

**Demo:**

[image]

The source code,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)     # 6 axes, returned as a 2-d array

for i in range(2):
    for j in range(3):
        plt.sca(axarr[i, j])                        # set the current axes instance 
        axarr[i, j].plot(i, j, 'ro', markersize=10) # plot 
        axarr[i, j].set_xlabel(str(tuple([i, j])))  # set x label
        axarr[i, j].get_xaxis().set_ticks([])       # hidden x axis text
        axarr[i, j].get_yaxis().set_ticks([])       # hidden y axis text

plt.show()
```

Comment: I have plot in `result` and I want add it to list with 6 plots

Comment: @ArseniyKrupenin, use `plt.sca` to set the current axes instance and then plot your data. Pls check the updated answer.

Comment: it returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_xlabel'`

Comment: @ArseniyKrupenin, use `axarr[0, 0].set_xlabel`

Comment: when I use `ax = ` it doesn't add plot to graph. I have only labels, but graph is empty

Comment: @ArseniyKrupenin, I just added a demo. pls check it.

Comment: axarr[0, 1] print graph not to subplot, it prints to separate graph

Answer (score 2):

`result` is of pandas.Series type, which doesn't have `add_subplot()` method.

use `fig.add_subplot(...)` instead

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37687133/5741205) (using seaborn module):

```
labels = df.columns.values
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 3, ncols = 4, gridspec_kw =  dict(hspace=0.3),figsize=(12,9), sharex = True, sharey=True)
targets = zip(labels, axes.flatten())
for i, (col,ax) in enumerate(targets):
    sns.boxplot(data=df, ax=ax, color='green', x=df.index.month, y=col)
```

You can use pandas plots instead of `seaborn`

Comment: How can I add this plot that contain in `result` to subplot?

Comment: when I use that it return `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_xlabel'`

Comment: I should to do this using `matplotlib` or `pandas`

Comment: @ArseniyKrupenin, well, then do it using `matplotlib` or `pandas` ;)

Comment: I don't understand, How can I add `ax`, that contain a plot to one of subplot

Comment: @ArseniyKrupenin, please read my comment about `Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example` and update your question accordingly, then SO community will be able to code a working example for you